# How come my animated CSS leaves artifacts (in Chrome)?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

If you look at http://keepskatinbro.com in Chrome, you'll notice that after you hover on titles that there will be artifacts left behind on the sides of the titles after you un-hover.

I got the idea from http://desandro.com (look at the bottom of the page). But Desandro's has no artifacts.

Here's the HTML:

```
<h1 id="logo">
    <a class="" id="home_link" href="http://keepskatinbro.com/" title="Keep Skatin' Bro" rel="home">
        <span id="keep">KEEP</span><br>
        <span id="skatin">SKATIN'</span><br>
        <span id="bro">BRO</span>
    </a>
</h1>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#header{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
    #header h1 a{
        color:#757575;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #181818, 2px 2px #181818, 3px 3px #181818, 4px 4px #181818, 5px 5px #181818, 6px 6px #181818, 7px 7px #181818, 8px 8px #181818;
        /*-moz-text-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);*/
    }
        #header h1 a:hover{
            color:#fff;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px #58e, 2px 2px #58e, 3px 3px #58e, 4px 4px #58e, 5px 5px #58e, 6px 6px #58e, 7px 7px #58e, 8px 8px #58e, 9px 9px #58e, 10px 10px #58e, 11px 11px #58e;
        }
```

Why might I have this problem? I've noticed it before when making other sites only in Chrome it seems... Yet Desandro doesn't have the artifacts on desandro.com.

Comment: couldn't reproduce the error, but notice that when hovering the titles the round borders of the post got square (in Chrome, not in FF)

Comment: FWIW, I do see some blue artifacts on the left after the hover in Chrome 10.0.648.127 on Windows 7.  I don't think I would have noticed them if I wasn't specifically looking for them though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry cannot comment yet. Can you write your code down?

By the way, just try to change the `mouseout` with `mouseleave` event or *viceversa*.

**EDIT**

It seems a Chrome bad hover event handling (you can test it by leaving the logo *gently*).

Force a negative, transparent shadow when the link is not hover:

```
#header h1 a {
    color: #757575;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #181818, 2px 2px #181818, 3px 3px #181818, 4px 4px #181818, 5px 5px #181818, 6px 6px #181818, 7px 7px #181818, 8px 8px #181818, -1px -1px transparent, -2px -2px transparent, -3px -3px transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luca, but its not JavaScript. It's pure HTML/CSS only though so that doesn't apply. I'm posting my source.

Comment: Wow, cool, thanks! That indeed is a good hack as a solution. Hehe. But Chrome devs do need to fix this little bug.

Comment: "But Chrome devs do need to fix this little bug." Then report it. http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines